# Automating Consolidation Processes

Tags: excel, vba, automation, report

My company is currently using excel for reporting where we have to collect data from various business units on a monthly basis. Each unit will send an excel file with 50 columns and 10-1000 row items each. After receiving each file, we will use vba to consolidate all these files. This consolidated master file is then split to various sections and sent to various personnels where any changes will have to be updated in the master file.

Is there any way that this process can be improved and automated using a different system?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that this process can be improved and automated using a different system?

Well, you already have the "low cost, low tech" solution.

---

The proper solution (until something better is invented) is a proper web application, which collects the data from the various users, processes it and then generates the necessary reports.

This endeavor is not something to be treated lightly, even if it sounds like a small task. Your company needs to understand what they want, and then contact some supplier companies to get an estimation of the costs.

The costs cover at least:

- the development of the application;
- the server on which the application will run after it is finished; can be a virtual server;
- the costs of training the employees to use the application properly;
- the costs of actually making the employees to use the application properly (the most resilient being usually the managers themselves);

Of course, I assume that you already have some network infrastructure, backups of all important data is done according to the best practices (by IT)...